# Ошибка AssertionError:

Tags: python

Создаю бота воспроизводящего музыку в голосовом канале.
Код:

```
class Song(disnake.PCMVolumeTransformer):

def search_tracks(ctx, query):
    stats = True
    while stats:
        try:
            searcher = client.search(str(query))
            if not searcher.tracks: raise searchError("Not searched tracks")
           # print(searcher.tracks['results'][0])
            track_object = searcher.tracks['results'][0]
            stats = False
            text = None
            lyrics = track_object.get_supplement()
            if lyrics.lyrics: text = lyrics.lyrics.full_lyrics
            with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO songs(name, requester, author, id, albumid, lyrics, guild) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (track_object['title'],ctx.author.id,track_object['artists'][0]['name'],track_object['id'],track_object['albums'][0]["id"],text,ctx.guild.id,))
                print("Success queued")
            return {
            "id": track_object["id"],
            "title": track_object["title"],
            "artist": track_object["artists"][0]["name"],
            "albumid": track_object["albums"][0]["id"],
            "lyrics": text
            }
        except NetworkError:
            pass
def download_track(ctx, track):
    stats = True
    while stats:
        try:
            client.tracks(track['id'])[0].download(f"songs/{ctx.guild.id}.mp3")
            stats = False
        except NetworkError:
            pass

# def check_playing(ctx):
#     voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
#     if not voice_state: return raise VoiceStateError("Not voice_state")
#     if not voice_state.is_playing(): return raise VoiceStateError("Not playing")


async def join_channel(ctx):
    voice = ctx.author.voice
    if not voice: return "notChannel"
    if voice:
        await voice.channel.connect()
        return None

async def leave_channel(ctx):
    voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_state:
        return "notState"
    if voice_state.is_connected():
        await voice_state.disconnect()
        return None
    else:
        return "notState"

async def stop(ctx):
    voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_state:
        return "notState"
    if voice_state.is_connected():
        #await voice_state.stop()
        await Song.leave_channel(ctx)
        return None
    else:
        return "notState"

async def my_after(ctx):
    #os.remove(f"songs/{ctx.guild.id}.mp3")
    voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_state.is_playing:
        names = []
        requesters = []
        artists = []
        ids = []
        albumids = []
        positions = []
        guilds = []
        lyrics = []
        with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as db:
            c = db.cursor()
            for n, r, a, i, ai, ly, g, p in c.execute("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE guild = ?", (ctx.guild.id,)):
                positions.append(p)
                names.append(n)
                requesters.append(r)
                artists.append(a)
                guilds.append(g)
                ids.append(i)
                albumids.append(ai)
                if n and not ly:
                    lyrics.append(None)
                else:
                    lyrics.append(ly)
            c.execute("DELETE FROM songs WHERE guild = ? AND position = ?", (guilds[0], positions[0],))
            print("Success removed")
        if positions[1]:
            #Song.download_track(ctx, {"id": ids[1]})
            await Song.play(ctx)
            return
        else:
            return

async def play_next(ctx):
    names = []
    requesters = []
    artists = []
    ids = []
    albumids = []
    positions = []
    guilds = []
    lyrics = []
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        for n, r, a, i, ai, ly, g, p in c.execute("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE guild = ?", (ctx.guild.id,)):
            positions.append(p)
            names.append(n)
            requesters.append(r)
            artists.append(a)
            guilds.append(g)
            ids.append(i)
            albumids.append(ai)
            if n and not ly:
                lyrics.append(None)
            else:
                lyrics.append(ly)
        c.execute("DELETE FROM songs WHERE guild = ? AND position = ?", (guilds[0], positions[0],))
        print("Success removed")
    whats = False
    try:
        whats = positions[1]
        whats = True
    except:
        whats = False
        return
    if whats:
        #Song.download_track(ctx, {"id": ids[1], "title": names[1], "artist": artists[1], "albumid": albumids[1], "lyrics": lyrics[1]})
        await Song.play(ctx)



async def play(ctx):
    voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_state:
        error = await Song.join_channel(ctx)
        if error:
            return error
    voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if voice_state.is_playing():
        return "alreadyPlay"
    ids = []
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        for n, r, a, i, ai, ly, g, p in c.execute("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE guild = ?", (ctx.guild.id,)):
            ids.append(i)
    Song.download_track(ctx, {'id': ids[0]})
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(Song.my_after(ctx))
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    voice_state.play(disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"songs/{ctx.guild.id}.mp3"), after=lambda ex: loop)

    return None

async def skip(ctx):
    voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if voice_state.is_playing():
        try:
            await voice_state.stop()
        except:
            pass
        await Song.play_next(ctx)
        return None
    else:
        return "notState"

def lyrics(ctx):
    names = []
    requesters = []
    artists = []
    ids = []
    albumids = []
    lyrics = []
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        for n, r, a, i, ai, ly, g, p in c.execute("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE guild = ?", (ctx.guild.id,)):
            names.append(n)
            requesters.append(r)
            artists.append(a)
            ids.append(i)
            albumids.append(ai)
            if n and not ly:
                lyrics.append(None)
            else:
                lyrics.append(ly)

    return {
    "name": names[0],
    "lyrics": lyrics[0]
    }

def now_playing(ctx):
    names = []
    requesters = []
    artists = []
    ids = []
    albumids = []
    positions = []
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        for n, r, a, i, ai, ly, g, p in c.execute("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE guild = ?", (ctx.guild.id,)):
            names.append(n)
            requesters.append(r)
            artists.append(a)
            ids.append(i)
            albumids.append(ai)
            positions.append(p)
    return {
    "name": names[0],
    "requester": requesters[0],
    "artist": artists[0],
    "pos": positions[0],
    "uri": f"https://music.yandex.ru/album/{ids[0]}/track/{albumids[0]}"
    }

def construct_queue(ctx):
    urls = []
    names = []
    positions = []
    texts = []
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        for n, r, a, i, ai, ly, g, p in c.execute("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE guild = ?", (ctx.guild.id,)):
            names.append(n)
            positions.append(p)
            urls.append(f"https:/music.yandex.ru/album/{ai}/track/{i}")
            texts.append(f"`{p}.` [**{n}**](https:/music.yandex.ru/album/{ai}/track/{i})")
    if texts == []: return None
    return "\n".join(list(map(str, texts)))
```

При запуске команды `/play`(она запускает функции `search_tracks`, `download_track`, и `play` в таком же порядке) бот заходит в голосовой канал, и в консоль выводится следующее:

> Success queued,
> Command raised an exception: AssertionError:

В голосовом канале полная тишина, как исправить это?

Comment: Внутренний AssertionError в asyncio может иметь много причин. По одной только ошибке определить не выйдет. Проверьте правильность своего кода.

Comment: @Flop-code Честно говоря, проблем никаких не вижу, ведь если этот after просто убрать, ошибок никаких нет. В функций my_after ошибок похоже тоже нет, ведь почти точная копия play_next никаких проблем не вызывает.